# Lightning aura event handler error

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I am using a custom application event (ackRequest) that I use to validate all components in a page. This event is fired in the afterRender of the community layout component.

The event is handled successfully by all components except one. The handler on all components does the same... trigger a second application event (ackResponse).

The one component that does not work throws this warning in Chrome:

> HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated. Chrome 69 and later will
>   ignore HPKP response headers.

All my components are on the same API version. For strategic reasons, I'm using version 38.0 with Locker Service turned off.

Any ideas why this might be happening or how better debug this event?

Comment: The warning is not an error, it's a warning. This is important to note because warnings do not *generally* prevent code from working. Whatever is going on most likely has nothing to do with this message. As far as debugging, have you tried the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en)?

Comment: It's as if the ackResponse is not being fired on the only component that throws the warning. I capture the ackResponse from all other components successfully but this one never gets logged. I tried enclosing the event call inside a try/catch and window.setTimeout but no luck. Lightning Inspector also didn't help. The ackResponse from the faulty component doesn't get logged and the action inspector doesn't show anything strange.